# Node.js - Taking it public?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, server, hardware

I'm learning how to program in Node.js, and so far I've been able to run it using my computer as a server, and log in through an IP address:8080 from other computers on the same router. But for the life of me, I can't seem to find any tutorials or anything for taking it public. E.g using my laptop from work to connect to the server hosted at home. I've searched free servers and am completely mixed up on SSH keys and github requirements and stuff with a bunch of others. I'm really mixed up.
I'm also thinking it would be much simpler (and 100% free on monthly payments) to buy my own hardware and run my own servers? Any tutorials on node.js hardware set ups?
Please help, I'm completely confused.

**EDIT**
I seem to have been a bit unclear. I'm going to use node.js to make games/apps with logins. When you "login" you automatically login to the server also. Not only from "work to home", I meant completely public as a multiplayer game.

Comment: Have you forwarded that port?

Comment: Do you know what port forwarding is?

Comment: I have googled it and am learning now!

Comment: Hey bro did you have any more questions? If my answer helped you please accept it as your answer. :) also you never answered me. do you have access to a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node doesn't have any specific hardware requirements or configuration. And can be hosted on anything.

I guess you don't have a dedicated ip address. So, your question seems to be all about network, routing and dealing with NAT. If you're not familiar with those, it might be not a bad idea to use external hosting.

But if you want to give it a try, this might be helpful - https://superuser.com/questions/121435/is-it-possible-to-host-a-web-server-from-behind-a-nat

Comment: I think it's networking too, I don't know much about networking, probably why I'm having trouble?

Comment: Yep. Reaching your laptop or home server from external network have nothing to do with a specific programming language or platform.

You've mentioned in comments bellow, that it's a learning project. Heroku does provide a free plan for your case. - https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Comment: Yes, it was all networking, got it running on public too! :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to setup a node server for free is using [AWS Free Tier.](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

Once you follow that link and setup a server...

You can follow along with this tutorial to get your server up and going, install node, install mongodb and even make an app that will run on the live server.

[Run throgh this tutorial](http://www.robert-drummond.com/2013/04/25/a-node-js-application-on-the-amazon-cloud-part-1-installing-node-on-an-ec2-instance/)

How I installed node on my server,

Personally I have a `VPS` from Bluehost. This cost me about $120 a month but lets me do whatever I want with my server. By whatever I want I mean install whatever I want...

I have npm install,
I installed node.js globally. 
I installed mongoDB.

I can run mongodb applications from anywhere and connect them to the MongoDB running on my server.

Having a VPS can come in handy as you can see... I suggest AWS free tier. Learn how to install all the things you want. Play with it. Break it and start over.

But when your done with all of that...
Be a Jedi Master!

Comment: Hello wuno, thank you for your help! I tried signing up for it but it asks for CC :( And I can't afford 120/mth :(((

Comment: Yes it does make you put a credit card in but you do not get charged unless you used that much. Do you have access to a virtual machine? like parallels?

Answer (score -1):

Besides hosting your own hardware, there are 2 options for what you describe.

One, use a portforwarding tool to make your home server accessible from your work, for example [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Two, deploy your `node.js` app to an online platform, for example [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). Most of these platforms have a low-performance free options.

Comment: I tried using those but they are really confusing. SSH, Git-Hub, I have all those trying to setup, but at the end it always asks for money ): I don't have a problem with that, but I don't want to spend anything I'm just learning!

Comment: Have you actually looked at OpenShift? They have a free plan. No asking for money. https://www.openshift.com/pricing/plan-comparison.html Same for GitHub - that's free for public repositories.